# Divide multidimensial array into arrays for data table

Tags: php, arrays

### How to Select key values into divided values

I want to create datatable in multidimensional array. I already finished first steps. Now I have some misunderstandings, I divided array into similar dates and now I want to divide again by similar key values. I gave example to better understanding.

What I have:

```
Array
(
[2016-05-01 00:00:00] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 0
                [oper_type] => 4
                [name_pay] => CLICK
                [name_oper] => Основной долг
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 1461128
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 1
                [oper_type] => 3
                [name_pay] => Наличные
                [name_oper] => Депозит
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 207866
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 1
                [oper_type] => 4
                [name_pay] => Наличные
                [name_oper] => Основной долг
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 707246
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 2
                [oper_type] => 3
                [name_pay] => Терминал
                [name_oper] => Депозит
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 95756
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [type_pay] => 2
                [oper_type] => 4
                [name_pay] => Терминал
                [name_oper] => Основной долг
                [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                [amount] => 329478
            )

    )
 )
```

My php cycle which I divided into dates

```
foreach ($data["reports"][1] as $value) {
      $bydate[$value['time_pay']][] = $value;
    }
```

What I want to get

```
Array
(
[2016-05-01 00:00:00] => Array
    (
        [Основной долг] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 0
                    [oper_type] => 4
                    [name_pay] => CLICK
                    [name_oper] => Основной долг
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 1461128
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 1
                    [oper_type] => 4
                    [name_pay] => Наличные
                    [name_oper] => Основной долг
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 707246
                )

                [2] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 2
                    [oper_type] => 4
                    [name_pay] => Терминал
                    [name_oper] => Основной долг
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 329478
                )
            )
        [Депозит] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 1
                    [oper_type] => 3
                    [name_pay] => Наличные
                    [name_oper] => Депозит
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 207866
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 2
                    [oper_type] => 3
                    [name_pay] => Терминал
                    [name_oper] => Депозит
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 95756
                )

                [2] => Array
                (
                    [type_pay] => 2
                    [oper_type] => 4
                    [name_pay] => Терминал
                    [name_oper] => Депозит
                    [time_pay] => 2016-05-01 00:00:00
                    [amount] => 329478
                )
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: why [депозит][2][name_oper] => Основной долг ?

Comment: oh sorry sir! that my mistake

Comment: `$bydate[$value['time_pay']][$value['name_oper']][] = $value;`

Comment: thank you sir! It was very simple and useful